# postgresql.conf not found when using volume mount

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have the following deployment:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: postgres-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: postgres
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: postgres
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: postgres-storage
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: postgres-persistent-volume-claim
      containers:
        - name: postgres
          image: prikshet/postgres
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5432
          volumeMounts:
            - name: postgres-storage
              mountPath: /var/lib/postgresql/data
              subPath: postgres
```

And when I include the lines 23-26 and do `kubectl apply`, the pod gives an error and doesn't run but when I remove the lines 23-36 the pod runs. I want to create a volume mount with the lines 23-26. The error when checking the logs of this pod is:

```
postgres: could not access the server configuration file "/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf": No such file or directory
```

postgres persistent volume claim is:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: postgres-persistent-volume-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi
```

How to fix this?

Comment: if i am not mistaken you are using the wrong subpath. try changing it from postgres to data

Comment: subpath has nothing to do with this

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two possibilities for this error to occur:

1. Your file `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` does not really actually exist. In this case, you need to create it before mounting it.
2. As [meaningqo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9250303/meaningqo) good mentioned in the comment, you are using the wrong [`subPath`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#using-subpath). Your file `/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf` exist, but you are trying to mount wrong file based on `subPath`. Look at the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65399714/what-is-the-difference-between-subpath-and-mountpath-in-kubernetes) the difference between `mountPath` and `subPath`:

> `mountPath`  shows where the referenced volume should be mounted in the container. For instance, if you mount a volume to  `mountPath: /a/b/c`, the volume will be available to the container under the directory  `/a/b/c`.
> Mounting a volume will make all of the volume available under  `mountPath`. If you need to mount only part of the volume, such as a single file in a volume, you use  `subPath`  to specify the part that must be mounted. For instance,  `mountPath: /a/b/c`,  `subPath: d`  will make whatever  `d`  is in the mounted volume under directory  `/a/b/c`
> Notice that when `subPath` is a folder, the content of the folder will be mounted to the `mountPath`

Comment: 1. if /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf didn't exist it wouldn't work even without persistent volume claim but does. 2. It doesn't work even after removing subPath

Comment: It is also possible that you have wrong permissions to this file. Please check it an attach results to the question.

Comment: What do you mean "if /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf didn't exist it wouldn't work even without persistent volume claim but does."? It looks quite strange.

Comment: I removed volumeMounts part and then I don't see the error. It works if postgres doesn't use persistent volume claim but the container's storage. It's still accessing the same directory for the postgresql.conf file